# How to deal with IE errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I don't get any error in firefox or firebug, but yet in IE I get invalid argument for some reason, and I can't figure out what is the invalid argument, the javascript halts when "error" is discovered .. what can I do to debug it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running IE8, you can use the [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx) by pressing F12.   You can also download them for [IE7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038).

Comment: You can also download the developer toolbar for IE 6. It makes life much much better.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Visual Studio you can use it directly to debug javascript.
First uncheck the advanced IE settings *"Disable script debugging"* then attach VS to the IExplorer process (Tools => Attach To Process then find the process).

Clearly this is not the easiest option here but can work in a pinch. If you are already using VS to do your development just disabling script debugging and launching your website with IE will allow the JS debugger to work automatically.

Answer (score 2):

get internet explorer 8, or the [internet explorer developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)

Answer (score 2):

Enable the script debugger in IE.

Note that with jquery or mootools 90% of the IE bugs (when it works fine in FF) is because I didn't explicitly extend an element I was working with.

In firefox you can just say `element.jquery_function()`, however with IE the element must be explicitly extended with `element = $(element)`, or just get in the habit of writing `$(element).jquery_function()`.

You didn't give enough info to debug your problem, but i'd guess that is a good place to start.

*note: I use mootools but i'm assuming this also applies to jquery*

Comment: I don't think `element.jquery_function()` works ... I always do `$(element).jquery_function()`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) over Firebug Lite.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cross-browser logging library such as my own [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on IE 8, that comes bundled with [developer tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you're on IE 7 or 6, there's the free [IE Developer Toolbar from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en).

There's also [Companion.JS](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/CompanionJS/HomePage) for IE 6/7.